# Internal SATA connectors on a PCI slot card

Tags: esata

I bought a dual eSATA PCI slot card and installed it in my pc.  What is the purpose of the internal connectors on the PCI cards?  Can I connect more SATA drives to them?

Comment: Probably, but since we don't know what adapter you have, or exactly which "internal connectors" you are referring to, it's impossible for us to do anything more than throw an educated guess.  What does the manual for the adapter say they are for?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can connect internal SATA drives on these connectors.

Depending on the model, they might share the port, such that you can use only one of the both (eSATA port and internal SATA).

Read the documentation or search for a manual online using the references printed on the die.